# How to convert an arraylist to a max heap in java using priority queue

Tags: java, syntax, priority-queue, max-heap

I know we can create a max heap using priority queue using Collections.reverseOrder(), but I need to pass the ArrayList in that place also. I tried to create a custom comparator just in case, but it doesnt seem to work. I would like to know the exact syntax of doing so.
Example/My knowledge:
1)creating an empty min heap -> PriorityQueue pqmin = new PriorityQueue();
2)Creating a min heap from an ArrayList arr -> PriorityQueue pqmin = new PriorityQueue(arr);
3)Creating an empty max heap -> PriorityQueue pqmax = new  PriorityQueue(Collections.reverseOrder());

My question: How to create max heap from existing arrayList using priorityQueue in Java

Answer (score 2):

Use the 3), then `addAll`. Or slightly better is to pass initial capacity

```
 PriorityQueue pqmax = new PriorityQueue(arr.size(), Collections.reverseOrder()); 
 pqmax.addAll(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such constructor in `PriorityQueue` that takes both a collection and a comparator.

But you can use `addAll` method:

```
PriorityQueue pqmax = new PriorityQueue(Collections.reverseOrder());
pqmax.addAll(arr);
```

Comment: okay thank you, but will the time complexity of doing addAll be O(n) or O(nlogn)

Comment: It is going to O(nlogn), because `PriorityQueue` has `addAll` inherited from `AbstractQueue`, where it just iterates over the collection.